# How to update html SELECT options with javascript or jquery, using values from other SELECT's (within eric hynds's multiselect widget)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Eric Hynds's jQuery multiselect widget to display a list of employees in several different sections on the same screen. I have several different multiselects on the same page, some of which have the same employees.

If a user selects (or unselects) an employee in one multiselect, I need to update the others to reflect the same choices.  I have 2 'optgroups' to consider as well, if possible, but those can be ignored for this purpose, unless it's relatively easy to handle.

The options could be refreshed with javascript or jquery, independent of the multiselect widget, and then the .refresh method could be called to update the widget. So, the solution to this may or may not use code from the widget to do the updating of the options.

Here are examples of two SELECTs and their options. Brian Jones appears in both. If Brian Jones is selected in the first example, how can I dynamically select him in the second example (and if possible, move him to the 'Assigned Employees' group)?  Same goes for if he is un-selected.

```
<select id="empSelection_01" name="employee_01" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Unassigned Employees">
        <option value="42954">Smith, Joe</option>
        <option value="30357">Jones, Brian</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Assigned Employees">
        <option value="42900">Brown, Laura</option>
        <option value="30399">Evans, Jessica</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<select id="empSelection_02" name="employee_02" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Unassigned Employees">
        <option value="42954">Doe, Jane</option>
        <option value="30357">Jones, Brian</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Assigned Employees">
        <option value="42900">Hix, Carolyn</option>
        <option value="30399">Evans, Jessica</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXTXv/1/)

```
$('#empSelection_01').multiselect({click:function(e){
    var isChecked = $(e.currentTarget).attr("checked")=="checked";
    var labelFrom = isChecked ? 'Unassigned Employees' : 'Assigned Employees';
    var labelTo = !isChecked ? 'Unassigned Employees' : 'Assigned Employees';

    var el = $('#empSelection_02').children('[label="' + labelFrom + '"]').children('[value="' + e.currentTarget.value + '"]');
    el.remove();
    $('#empSelection_02').children('[label="' + labelTo + '"]').append(el);
    if (isChecked) {
        el.attr('selected', 'selected');
    } else {
        el.removeAttr('selected');
    }        
    $('#empSelection_02').multiselect('refresh');
}});
```

It's example how you can manipulate with this plugin, but it's not enough to solve you problem. You neeed some logic, to take options into consideration, and indicate in which group options must be located, especially if many-to-many connections is possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. There are actually 40 or 50 multiselects on the same screen. If one changes, I need to take into account all others (not just one other, like this example). Can your example be easily adjusted for that?

Comment: I think you need more detail algorithm to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this JavaScript, which receives the ID of the SELECT that was just changed, and then uses values within that SELECT to process all other SELECT's on the screen:

---

```
 function refreshEmps(currID){

 var sel = document.getElementById(currID);
 var opt = sel.options;
 var checkedVals = new Array();


 // save checked values ***************************

 for (i=0; i<opt.length; i++){

   if (opt[i].selected==true) {
         checkedVals[checkedVals.length]=opt[i].value;
   }

 }

 //update remaining SELECT's ***************************

 var ddCounter = 0; //


 while(document.getElementById("employeeDD_" + ddCounter)!=null) {

 var sel2 = document.getElementById("employeeDD_" + ddCounter);

 if (currID!=sel2.id) {

var opt2 = sel2.options;

for (i=0; i<opt2.length; i++){


     for (j=0; j<checkedVals.length; j++) {

      if(opt2[i].value==checkedVals[j]) {       
        opt2[i].disabled=true;
        opt2[i].style.color = 'red';
          }

    }//end for

 }


  }//end if

  ddCounter++;

 }//end WHILE

 $("select").multiselect('refresh');


 }
```